# Mongodb Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');


var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bookAPI');

var Book = require('./models/bookModel');

var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3002;


var bookRouter = express.Router();

bookRouter.route('/Books')
    .get(function(req,res){

        Book.find(function(err,books){
            if(err)
                console.log(err);
            else
                res.json(books);
        });
    });


app.use('/api', bookRouter);



app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('welcome to my API!');
});

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Gulp is running my app on  PORT: ' + port);
});
```

Bookmodel.js file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var bookModel = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    author: {type: String},
    genre: {type: String},
    read: {type: Boolean, default:false}
});

module.exports= mongoose.model('Book', bookModel);
```

My gulpfile is:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');


gulp.task('default', function(){
    nodemon({
        script: 'app.js',
        ext: 'js',
        env: {
            PORT:8000
        },
        ignore: ['./node_modules/**']
    })
    .on('restart', function(){
        console.log('Restarting');
    });
});
```

However I keep getting the error:

```
Gulp is running my app on  PORT: 8000
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
  at null.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Documents/NodeAndExpress/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:549:74)
```

This is quite frustrating because I am following a Pluralsight course very closely. I've installed all the neccessary npm packages etc. It is definitely the mongoose connection that is causing the error as it goes away when I remove the connection line. The database has not been created but the instructor mentioned it should be automatically created if it doesn't already exist.

I've tried starting the mongoose connection manually with `mongod` but I get the error:

```
 ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
```

Comment: What does ./models/bookModel.js look like? Because I've ran into the occasional issue where mongoose's connect is happening too late unless you use the same instance of mongoose, as in only require mongoose once.

Comment: The main issue here is that your MongoDB server isn't starting. It's also giving you a potential solution. As a quick fix, you could try this: `mkdir /tmp/data; mongod --dbpath /tmp/data`

Comment: @robertklep You gun. Worked. Please create an official answer. Also please try explain why this solution is necessary and a potential "clean fix". I have no idea why this step was skipped on PS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few moving parts here:

- Mongoose, which offers object modeling for MongoDB;
- MongoDB itself, which is the database(-server) that will store the documents you create with Mongoose.

In terms of installation, both are independent: when you install Mongoose, you don't automatically install MongoDB (and vice versa). Also, when you run a Node.js script that uses Mongoose, it will not automatically start MongoDB, that's something that needs to be done separately.

In your case, MongoDB isn't running, so Mongoose can't connect to it. All that Mongoose can do is complain about that (*"failed to connect to ..."*).

To start MongoDB, you can use the `mongod` command line program. You usually need to provide it a directory where it can store its database; on my system (Mac OS X), that directory is `/var/db/mongodb`, but that's not necessarily the best location (it depends on which OS you are running).

As a quick fix, you can provide a temporary directory to act as database directory:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/data
$ mongod --dbpath /tmp/data
```

This isn't ideal for real life purposes because `/tmp` is usually emptied during system boot, so your database will be removed as well at that point. However, for testing purposes, it's okay. As long as you are aware that after a reboot your database will be empty again.

At some point you want to have the system automatically start MongoDB at system boot, however, it depends on your OS how exactly you need to configure that.

Answer (score 1):

I expect your mongodb installation to have an error due to the dbpath error. dbpath is a configuration parameter of mongodb: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath

So maybe you try to reinstall mongodb or change the configuration option to an existing path.